# How to get fuzzy matches of given set of names in python polars dataframe?

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to implement a name duplications for one of our use case.

Here I have a set of 10 names along with their index column as below.

[image]

[image]

Here I would like to calculate fuzzy metrics(Levenshtein,JaroWinkler) per each of name combinations using a rapidxfuzz module as below.

```
from rapidfuzz import fuzz
from rapidfuzz.distance import Levenshtein,JaroWinkler
```

```
round(Levenshtein.normalized_similarity(name_0,name_1),5)
round(JaroWinkler.similarity(name_0,name_1),5)
```

For example: idx-0 name Mallesham Yamulla to be paired with names having indexes sequence (1,9) names[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9)] and calculate their levenshtein and Jarowrinkler similar percentages.

Next idx-1 name with names index sequence (2,9), idx-2 with name index sequence (3,9), idx-3 with (4,9) so on so forth till (8,9)

The expected output would be :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# Create example dataframe.
In [83]: df = pl.DataFrame(
    ...:     [
    ...:          pl.Series("full_name", ["Aaaa aaaa", "Baaa abba", "Acac acca", "Dada dddd"])
    ...:     ]
    ...: ).with_row_count(name="idx", offset=0)

In [84]: df
Out[84]: 
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ idx ┆ full_name │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ u32 ┆ str       │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ Baaa abba │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ Acac acca │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd │
└─────┴───────────┘

# Join dataframe with itself in a cross join and remove rows where idx == idx.
In [85]: df_combinations = df.join(
    ...:     df,
    ...:     how="cross",
    ...:     on="idx",
    ...:     suffix="_2",
    ...: ).filter(
    ...:     pl.col("idx") != pl.col("idx_2")
    ...: )

In [86]: df_combinations
Out[86]: 
shape: (12, 4)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ idx ┆ full_name ┆ idx_2 ┆ full_name_2 │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ u32 ┆ str       ┆ u32   ┆ str         │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 1     ┆ Baaa abba   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 2     ┆ Acac acca   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 3     ┆ Dada dddd   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ Baaa abba ┆ 0     ┆ Aaaa aaaa   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ... ┆ ...       ┆ ...   ┆ ...         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ Acac acca ┆ 3     ┆ Dada dddd   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 0     ┆ Aaaa aaaa   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 1     ┆ Baaa abba   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 2     ┆ Acac acca   │
└─────┴───────────┴───────┴─────────────┘

# 
In [91]: df_combinations.with_columns(
    ...:     [
    ...          # Combine "idx" and "idx_2" columns to one struct column.
    ...:         pl.struct(pl.col(["idx", "idx_2"])).alias("idx_comb"),
    ...:         # Combine "full_name" and "full_name_2" columns to one struct column.
    ...:         pl.struct(pl.col(["full_name", "full_name_2"])).alias("full_name_comb"),
    ...:     ]
    ...: ).with_columns(
    ...:     [
    ...:         # Run custom functions on struct column.
    ...:         pl.col("full_name_comb").apply(lambda t: Levenshtein.normalized_similarity(t["full_name"], t["full_name_2"])).alias("levenshtein"),
    ...:         pl.col("full_name_comb").apply(lambda t: JaroWinkler.similarity(t["full_name"], t["full_name_2"])).alias("jarowinkler"),
    ...:     ]
    ...: )
Out[91]: 
shape: (12, 8)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────┬─────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ idx ┆ full_name ┆ idx_2 ┆ full_name_2 ┆ idx_comb  ┆ full_name_comb            ┆ levenshtein ┆ jarowinkler │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ u32 ┆ str       ┆ u32   ┆ str         ┆ struct[2] ┆ struct[2]                 ┆ f64         ┆ f64         │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 1     ┆ Baaa abba   ┆ {0,1}     ┆ {"Aaaa aaaa","Baaa abba"} ┆ 0.666667    ┆ 0.777778    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 2     ┆ Acac acca   ┆ {0,2}     ┆ {"Aaaa aaaa","Acac acca"} ┆ 0.555556    ┆ 0.637037    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 3     ┆ Dada dddd   ┆ {0,3}     ┆ {"Aaaa aaaa","Dada dddd"} ┆ 0.333333    ┆ 0.555556    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ Baaa abba ┆ 0     ┆ Aaaa aaaa   ┆ {1,0}     ┆ {"Baaa abba","Aaaa aaaa"} ┆ 0.666667    ┆ 0.777778    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ... ┆ ...       ┆ ...   ┆ ...         ┆ ...       ┆ ...                       ┆ ...         ┆ ...         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ Acac acca ┆ 3     ┆ Dada dddd   ┆ {2,3}     ┆ {"Acac acca","Dada dddd"} ┆ 0.111111    ┆ 0.444444    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 0     ┆ Aaaa aaaa   ┆ {3,0}     ┆ {"Dada dddd","Aaaa aaaa"} ┆ 0.333333    ┆ 0.555556    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 1     ┆ Baaa abba   ┆ {3,1}     ┆ {"Dada dddd","Baaa abba"} ┆ 0.333333    ┆ 0.555556    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 2     ┆ Acac acca   ┆ {3,2}     ┆ {"Dada dddd","Acac acca"} ┆ 0.111111    ┆ 0.444444    │
└─────┴───────────┴───────┴─────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Would this be a feasible solution if I have more than 100K?.

Comment: I'm executing it on 50K entries, Ipython Kernel is getting killed

Comment: You will need a lot of RAM for 100k entries as the dataframe after the cross join will be 100k to the power of 2= 10^10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Change 3 to 1000 or 10000 to split up the cross join part in multiple iterations with a smaller dataframe, which you can run the levenshtine/jarowinkler functions on. That function output you probably should filter to remove rows for which the values are too low.
In [97]: for x in range(0, df.height, 3):
    ...:     df_combinations_x = df.join(
    ...:         df.slice(offset=x, length=3),
    ...:         how="cross",
    ...:         on="idx",
    ...:         suffix="_2",
    ...:     ).filter(
    ...:         pl.col("idx") != pl.col("idx_2")
    ...:     )
    ...:     print(df_combinations_x)
    ...: 
shape: (9, 4)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ idx ┆ full_name ┆ idx_2 ┆ full_name_2 │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ u32 ┆ str       ┆ u32   ┆ str         │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 1     ┆ Baaa abba   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 2     ┆ Acac acca   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ Baaa abba ┆ 0     ┆ Aaaa aaaa   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ Baaa abba ┆ 2     ┆ Acac acca   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ... ┆ ...       ┆ ...   ┆ ...         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ Acac acca ┆ 1     ┆ Baaa abba   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 0     ┆ Aaaa aaaa   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 1     ┆ Baaa abba   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ Dada dddd ┆ 2     ┆ Acac acca   │
└─────┴───────────┴───────┴─────────────┘
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬───────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ idx ┆ full_name ┆ idx_2 ┆ full_name_2 │
│ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ u32 ┆ str       ┆ u32   ┆ str         │
╞═════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ Aaaa aaaa ┆ 3     ┆ Dada dddd   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ Baaa abba ┆ 3     ┆ Dada dddd   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ Acac acca ┆ 3     ┆ Dada dddd   │
└─────┴───────────┴───────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Kernel is still getting killed out (18GB RAM) even with splitting approach.